# Remove element by id:number from JSON object by clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Im building a blog with JS, Json, Ajax and Jquery.

Every post element in my DOM has a "Erase" button. Every element is posted from ajax (Json object)

I would like to know, how can i erase the choosen element by click on its erase button.

Part of my code

```
 {
      "title": "Test",
      "body": "Test body",
      "createdDate": "2019-01-05 01:42:38",
      "id": 5
    }

function deletePost(id){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('DELETE', '/posts/' + id);
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            let postsArray = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log('Error ' + xhr.statusText);
        }
    }
}

<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="delBtn" value="Radera">

$('#blog').on('click','#delBtn',function(){ 
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: delete from the DOM and server database?

Comment: Yes @ewwink. One by one by clicking the erase button on every post.